# Straightforward way to wrap class function and use super in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing an application in ES6 and transpiling with babel. I have a series of objects that are shapes (Square, Rectangle, Trapezoid, etc.)

I want to be able to make some of these objects "special" objects, for example, to have a double border or rounded corners. But I don't want to subclass every object (i.e, DoubleBorderRectangle, DoubleBorderSquare)

This seems like a good place to introduce a decorator.

I am running into issues, however, when I want to decorate a method that uses super.

For instance, I have a class like this:

```
class Trapezoid extends Sprite {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        this.type = "Trapezoid";
        //other trapezoid specific functions here.
    }
    draw(ctx) {
        super.draw(ctx);
        //specific code for drawing trapezoid here.
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to instantiate a special trapezoid, say with a double border, using a decorator:

```
function doubleBorder(shape) {

    shape.draw = function(ctx) {

       //draw the trapezoid. 
       super.draw(ctx);

       //double border drawing stuff here.
    }

    return shape;
}
```

And instantiate:

```
 let trapezoid = new Trapezoid(0,0,100,100);
 let doubleBorderTrapezoid = doubleBorder(trapezoid);
```

One issue is that babel doesn't like super used outside of a class. Which is understandable. Is there a way to get hold of the shape's superclass and pass it the correct context without creating a throwaway object?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but you can implement a number of ways so it comes down to style and lines of code.

1) Create a function in the superclass to add the double outline, assumes this is going to be used by multiple subclasses.

2) Create an array of decorator functions (superclass or specific subclass) then check for these in draw (super or sub) and apply.

```
const myDecorator = (ctx) => { ... }
...
draw(ctx) {
  this.decorators.forEach(draw => draw(ctx));
}
```

Depending on your use case the first is more clean OOP, the second is more composition functional leaning.